# Erro: Tipos Incompatíveis

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou rodando um PROCV numa coluna, procurando valores de outra. O código roda até certo valor e aparece o erro citado. Mas não há diferença nos números, inclusive já coloquei todos valores como o primeiro para testar e continuar dando o mesmo erro (sempre na 8ª linha da coluna).

segue o código

i = 2

```
Do Until Range("F" & i) = ""

    Range("H" & i).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-2],C[-5],1,FALSE), ""OK"")"

        If Cells(8, i).Value = "OK" Then    'Aqui aparece o erro
            Cells(8, i).Copy
            Sheets("Teste").Select
            Cells(j, 2).Select
            Sheets("Planilha4").Select

        j = j + 1
        End If
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Veja [a documentação da propriedade Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-cells-property-excel), em que a sintaxe é: `.Cells(Linha,Coluna)`. Então já que deseja a coluna H, tente inverter 8 e i. Portanto, ficaria: `If Cells(i, 8).Value = "OK" Then`

Comment: Já tinha invertido, não resolveu o problema. O erro da na 1ª linha da tabela ao invés da 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leandro,

Além da inversão conforme o colega acima sinalizou, tem outro problema no seu código. Quando o `PROCV` não localiza o valor procurado, ele retorna um #N/D e isto está causando o erro de incompatibilidade de tipo.

Para resolver basta incluir um `IFERROR` (`SEERRO` no Excel em pt) e indicar qual valor você quer que apareça, em caso de erro. Testei o código abaixo e funcionou perfeitamente aqui, repare que em caso de erro, irá aparecer "NÃO LOCALIZADO".

```
i = 2
j = 2

Do Until Range("F" & i) = ""

    Range("H" & i).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-2],C[-5],1,FALSE)=R[0]C[-2], ""OK""),""NÃO LOCALIZADO"")"

        a = Cells(i, 8).Value

        If Cells(i, 8).Value = "OK" Then
            Cells(i, 8).Copy
            Sheets("Teste").Select
            Cells(j, 2).Select
            Sheets("Planilha4").Select

        j = j + 1
        End If
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Júnior, com essa mudança, aparece o erro "erro de definição de aplicativo ou de definição de objeto" na linha do 'Cells(j, 2)...'. Você sabe porquê?

Comment: @LeandroLazari Provavelmente porque o valor de j é igual a 0. Logo abaixo de `i=2`, tente fazer `j=2`

Comment: Funcionou Junior! Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Obrigado @danieltakeshi.

Comment: @LeandroLazari, acredito que haja um problema na fórmula do PROCV. Creio que o correto seja:  =IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-2],C[-5],1,FALSE)=R[0]C[-2], ""OK""),""NÃO LOCALIZADO"")". Faça o teste aí.